# Sharepoint 2013 Search from keyword file attribute

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

**What I want to do**

I have some files (jpg, doc) with keywords in theirs file attributes (visibles in the Windows Explorer, in the files properties). I want to be able to find them in a Sharepoint Search website from these keywords. Unfortunately, I don't find a way to set the crawl engine to index this file attribute.

**What I've done for now**

In the Sharepoint Search Administration I've created a source content from a files share. After a full crawl I can now find my files from their filename, title, author... through a Sharepoint Search website.

Any idea ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this interesting post : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/feee374d-461e-4340-918a-c360116e3624/including-dockeywords-metadata-for-searching

This is exactly what I want to do but nobody seems to be able to make it work. Microsoft bug ?